# How to tell typescript compile about not explicit inheritance

Tags: typescript, types, declaration

I've created mySomeClass and in constructor I'm using Object.assign method to copy all the properties of someObject to mySomeClass.

How can I tell to the compiler about types copied methods?

```
import someObject from 'someLib';

class A {
 constructor(){
  Object.assign(this, someObject);
 }
}

let a = new A();

a.trigger();
```

> Error:(149, 9) TS2339: Property 'trigger' does not exist on type 'a'.

Comment: Could you use inheritance to achieve what you want?

Comment: if i cant, i not to created this question

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using simple inheritance if you can, but if you can't you could try one of the following:

You can just declare the methods and not initialize them:

```
class A {
    trigger!: () => void
    constructor() {
        Object.assign(this, someObject);
    }
}
```

Or if you are looking for a more general solution that does not force you to redeclare all fields you could do the following:

```
function assignExtends<T>(target: T): new () => T {
    return class {
        constructor() {
            Object.assign(this, target);
        }
    } as any
}
let someObject = {
    trigger() {
        console.log("D")
    }
}

class A extends assignExtends(someObject) {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
}
```

Comment: @ruSl0n which version are you using ? What module are you importing ?

Comment: i imported 'backbone-events-standalone', ver 2.8.1

Answer (score 0):

Use the `extends` keyword to make inheritance in a way typescript will better understand; like so:

```
class A {
    field: string;
}

class B extends A { }

let b = new B();
console.log(b.field); // works!
```

Comment: not work for me, because A = {} (is created object, not class or func)